# How do you create and render a 3D Fractal?

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, render, fractals

So I've been assigned a recursive art project for my AP CS class and have a bunch of spare time, so I've decided to try something a little bit more ambitious.

**My plan is to create a 3D fractal**, either rendered and shaded in a visualization with GL, or represented via spatially mapping the respective equations' outputs to points on a cube and drawing those. If this explanation seems unclear, please check out the links at the bottom for images. Now, I don't need the fractal to be able to be modified in-program. I just need it to render a single BufferedImage, which I'll be putting directly on a JFrame.

My experience in Java, as far as this project goes, is a bit limited. I've drawn Mandelbrot and Julia set fractals before, but **I have little to no experience drawing/rendering objects in 3D in Java.** This is all stuff I can look up and figure out myself though, so no worries here.

Thus, the question: **How does one map a fractal that should be in the 2nd dimension** (e.g. log(no. of subdivided entities)*log(side length of subdivision) = 2) **to the 3rd dimension** (e.g. log(no. of subdivided entities)*log(side length of subdivision) = 3)? I'm lost trying to mathematically work this out, and I believe there is a more organized approach to go about this circumventing a lot of the math that already exists.

Also, if you are aware of **a structured approach** to render a 2D fractal, as drawn by a formula, and render it in 3D, provided the respective formula is provided (power is raised), please let me know. I've heard of Ray Tracers, no idea what they are, a brief summary would be cool.

Here are links with pictures of the result I want to obtain:

http://2008.sub.blue/assets/0000/4575/power8_large.jpg

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rK8jhCVlCtU

Comment: From what I can see, the picture you linked to is a [Mandelbulb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbulb). If you haven't already done so,you might want to look at the linked Wikipedia article, which provides formulas that should be usable in an algorithmic approach.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the image is an example of a [Mandelbulb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbulb). The is a similar iteration formula to the Mandlebrot set but using 3D points and a novel idea of what raising a 3D point to a power means.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I checked out the Mandelbulb and it sounds pretty interesting. The formulas on the Wiki appear to return a set of <x,y,z> coordinates on three dimensions. How do I render a 3D object such as this given x,y,z coordinates?

Comment: I think you need to use a volumetric method. Just as with the Mandelbrot set you iterate over all the pixels in the image and workout which colour it should be. For the  Mandelbulb you iterate over each voxel in a 3D region. You will just want to use the voxels on the boundary. I've not draw one myself so can't tell you more than is in the links from the wikipedia article.